# Update Database Fields Based On Date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need a trigger that updates a table row field by checking date that is stored in their own field without any interaction of user. i.e I am working on a project where I have to book rooms for user for a particular date and time and at that case I want to show room status as "booked" but after expiry of that date and time our database automatically update room status "booked" to "available". means I want that database keep track of their record and update it automatically. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Don't use a trigger for this. Just put whatever logic you were going to put into the trigger to determine this into the `SELECT` query instead. You can encapsulate the logic in a (non persisted) computed column on the table.

Comment: And one important point I forgot to mention is that you can't create a trigger that fires at a specific time anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As Martin Smith said in the comments, there is no Date/Time based trigger, therefore you have two options.

1. **Batch Update** - Use a batch process to update the data.  This requires determining how often the data needs to change and then creating a batch process that runs at least that often to update the data.  If the information changes once a day this might be acceptable, but as the update need gets more frequent this solution becomes less usable.
2. **Dynamic Evaluation** - As Martin Smith suggested, determine availability when the information is requested.  This can be in the select statement itself or you can use a computed column on the table.  In either case the data will be as up to date as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I have used Event Scheduler. There is a similar function in SQLServer 2008, see [Creating and Attaching Schedules to Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175138%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

For your purpose, you can set it to start everyday at 00:01.